# A babysitter or a childminder?

Tags: british-english, transatlantic-differences

I have recently had a lesson about jobs. I noticed that a different term 'childminder' is used for a babysitter in the UK. Is that right? Does anybody know if it's common?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I advise you to do two things to improve the quality of the answer: (1) show a little research. What does a dictionary or another resource say about childminder? That saves readers a step, and helps answerers go beyond playing fetch; (2) fix the spelling error with "babysittor." These changes would help make your question more accessible to a broader audience.

Comment: The age of the child being looked after is relevant. If the child is 12 years old, that is not "baby sitting."

Comment: Though some 12 year olds who need a babysitter might resent that they need a babysitter, if they have a babysitter, that person is babysitting them. Children who are clearly not babies get babysat.

Answer (score 4):

Her majesty's government has a [legal definition of a childminder](https://www.gov.uk/become-childminder-nanny). It is someone who is paid to look after someone else's children in their own home. This is distinct from a babysitter or nanny who looks after someone else's children in that someone else's home.

Comment: In the US, we would likely call this *daycare*. If we wanted to note that it was in a residential home, we might call it *in-home daycare* / *home daycare*.

Comment: Being a childminder is an occupation. Babysitting is an informal arrangement (sometimes paid) to be present in the parents' house with their child while they go out.